# Ruby get cancel to be button and not link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, cancel-button

I have some ruby code to create a basic blog.

I want buttons that allow a user to update or cancel when updating their password. This is in a 'Application Helper'

I want these as buttons but unsure how to make the 'cancel' a button to go back. It is currently just java script and text but the update user is a button.

the code is below

```
module ApplicationHelper


# Creates a submit button with the given name with a cancel link
  # Accepts two arguments: Form object and the cancel link name
  def submit_or_cancel(form, name='Cancel')
    form.submit + " or " +
      link_to(name, 'javascript:history.go(-1);', :class => 'cancel')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of this but you can try to do something like this

```
module ApplicationHelper
# Creates a submit button with the given name with a cancel link
  # Accepts two arguments: Form object and the cancel link name
  def submit_or_cancel(form, name='Cancel')
    form.submit + " or " +
      link_to(name, '#',:onclick => 'history.go(-1);', :class => 'cancel')
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps you out